# Cannot import video from a DV camcorder over FireWire in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, camera, firewire, dv

I have a JVC GR-D320 miniDV camcorder that has a FireWire interface. I recently upgraded to Windows 7 RTM (64 bit, fresh installation).

When I connect my camcorder through FireWire, I can see it in Device Manager without any warnings or problems, but I cannot capture videos from my miniDV tapes. After connecting, AutoPlay displays:

> Import Video could not find a compatible digital video device. Verify
>   that the digital video device is properly connected and turned on.

When using Windows Live Photo Gallery after selecting the import option, my camera is not listed.

The camera used to work perfectly on the same hardware before upgrading to Windows 7 RTM 64 bit (it used to work fine on Windows XP SP3 32 bit).

Googling revealed that people had the exact same problems in Vista, but no solution was provided. Any help?

Comment: have you tried any 3rd party 32-bit software?

Comment: Not yet, but my guess is that it's not a software issue, but a driver one.

Comment: Not a solution, but I will mention that I've done a lot of DV and HDV importing over 1394 (from Sony cameras) on Vista, 7, and 8/8.1. So it isn't a general problem with these OSs.

Comment: Although the device appears in Device Manager, is it the latest version of the driver? If you can find the hardware Ids and driver version and update your question it may help. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you still have the Windows XP disk you can install it in VirtualBox and it works for me.

I have an old Panasonic camcorder and it used to work well with my old laptop with windows vista but suddenly stopped working. No driver. the one included with Windows (it did not download it)

Had to remove it from the device manager and reinstall driver and it worked like external display port. So controls were still on the camcorder.

Answer (score -1):

This sounds like camera driver issues. Have you checked the manufacturer website for updated Vista/Windows 7 compatible drivers? The drivers for the camera might only work in Windows XP for now. If people are having problems in Vista, I would imagine Windows 7 compatibility would be a problem also.

Comment: The camera uses a standard communication interface for DV over FireWire. The driver for this is built into Windows (XP, Vista, 7), so the manufacturer does not supply any drivers.

Comment: then updates should be provided by Microsoft.  but check the camera mfg's site just in case; it's possible they'll pick up the slack if enough of their customers are complaining.